# Dynamically Created Input (type=“file”) and Form Elements

Tags: javascript, php, html

As slowly devloping my app because I am still learning I ran into another problem.

I generated with JS a form, a file input and a submit input in order to upload some photos and to display their thumnails with a .php file. I have this code. I mention that this is a part of a cascade menu.

When I try to upload the photos I get this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null " in .php file.

I also want to mention that the same php script works fine if the HTML elements are not generated and they are witten in pure HTML.

I know this php script is not complete but this is only for testing purposes.

JS

```
var form = document.createElement("FORM");
    second_plate.appendChild(form);
    form.setAttribute("id" , "form");
    form.setAttribute("action" , "upload.php");
    form.setAttribute("method" , "post");
    form.setAttribute("enctype" , "multipart/form-data");
    form.setAttribute("target" , "iframe");
    console.log(form);

    var inputpic = document.createElement("INPUT");
    form.appendChild(inputpic);
    inputpic.setAttribute("type" , "file");
    inputpic.setAttribute("name" , "file");
    inputpic.setAttribute("id" , "file");


    var submitpic = document.createElement("INPUT");
    form.appendChild(submitpic);
    submitpic.setAttribute("id" , "submit");
    submitpic.setAttribute("name" , "submit");
    submitpic.setAttribute("type" , "submit");
    submitpic.setAttribute("value" , "Upload photo");

    var photosplace = document.createElement("DIV");
    second_plate.appendChild(photosplace);
    photosplace.setAttribute("id" , "photos");

    var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    second_plate.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.setAttribute("id" , "iframe");   
    iframe.setAttribute("name" , "iframe");
    iframe.style.width = "0%";  
    iframe.style.height = "0%"; 
    iframe.style.display = "none";
```

PHP

```
<?php

        if ($_FILES['file']['size'] > 0) {

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], uploads/".$_FILES['file']"name"])) {

                ?>
                <script>
                    document.getElementById("file").value = "";
                    updatepic("<?php echo 'uploads/'.$_FILES['file']["name"]; ?>");             
                </script>
                <?php
            }
        }


?>
```

Comment: Where does the variable `second_plate` get defined? Also, is your JS code being called after the DOM is ready?

Comment: Second_plate is a menu plate also generated with js. It represents a cascade menu